# Is there a filesystem that supports inheritance?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am wondering if (in any state of development) there exists a filesystem that can inherit files from another filesystem, but changes made on that mount point would only affect that mount point.

This would be sort of like a distributed filesystem that only synchronizes inward and never outward, and only if the lack of changes permit that action.

Comment: UnionFS does that, it's supposed to support Linux, though I'm not sure what distros it's included in as I'm a BSD user. Apparently AuFS does some thing similar too, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking about doing something like [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) on top of something like ro mounted NFS.

Knoppix and other LiveCD distros use unionfs to do the same thing using a disk file on a USB stick or in some setups a disk partition.

I haven't done a setup like this for about 10 years or so.